# Angular mat-tab-group and tinyMCE

Tags: angular, angular-material, tinymce

I want to place an instance of `tinyMCE` on a tab-group. On one tab I have tinyMCE on another just a regular `textarea`. Switching the tabs causes a failure in `tinyMCE` and the content is not any longer editable - if `tinyMCE` is displayed at all. Looking for solution I come up with the following:

```
  <mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" (selectedIndexChange)="unloadTinyMce($event)"
      (animationDone)="updateEditor()">
      <mat-tab label="HTML Cover">
        <editor id="tinyMCE" [init]="tinyMceSettings.defaultWithInlineImages" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
          [(ngModel)]="myEntity.textHtml"></editor>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="PDF Cover">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label i18n>Text for PDF</mat-label>
          <textarea matInput rows="10" i18n-placeholder="Text for PDF" placeholder="Text for PDF"
            [(ngModel)]="myEntity.textText"> </textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

So basically following different hints that I should unload `tinyMCE` when switching the tab and loading when switching back. When animation ends the content is reloaded. I figured out that it has to set to `0ms` otherwise it won't work.

```
  unloadTinyMce(value): void {
    this.currentTabIndex = value;
    console.log('tab sel:' + value)
  }

  updateEditor() {
    console.log('finished animation ')
    if (this.currentTabIndex == 0) {
      const settings = Object.assign({}, TinyMceSettings.defaultWithInlineImages, { selector: '#tinyMCE' });
      tinymce.init(settings)
    } else {
      tinymce.remove('tinyMCE'); //the id of your textarea
    }
  }
```

So, right now I have the following three major issues:

1. The content of `tinyMCE` is not editable
2. I have no clue how to bind the content to the `ngModel` - in specific to `myEntity.textHTML`
3. Sometimes it fails to load the settings sometimes not. I guess that's some sort of timing.

Is there a working code how to use `tinyMCE` on a `mat-tab-group`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to lazy-load the mat-tab content.

This forces the tab content (and tinyMCE) to be rebuild when you change tabs:

```html
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="handleTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="First Tab">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <editor [apiKey]="apiKey" [(ngModel)]="firstEditorValue"></editor>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Second Tab">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <editor [apiKey]="apiKey" [(ngModel)]="secondEditorValue"></editor>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Docs: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

Comment: I'm surprised that this solution works as well. This is even more simplistic than my provided solution. I like this approach very much. :-) Thx for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

I followed simply the [StoryBook](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular/tree/master/stories/materialtabs) from the Angular/tinyMCE component. The solution simply enables or disables in the `mat-tab-group` the component with the `editor`, i.e.

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup (selectedTabChange)="handleTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="First Tab">
    <editor [(ngModel)]="firstEditorValue" *ngIf="activeTabIndex===0"></editor>
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Second Tab">
    <editor [(ngModel)]="secondEditorValue" *ngIf="activeTabIndex===1"></editor>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and

```
  @ViewChild('tabGroup', { static: false }) public tabGroup: any;
  public activeTabIndex: number | undefined = undefined;
  public firstEditorValue = '';
  public secondEditorValue = '';

  public handleTabChange(e: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.activeTabIndex = e.index;
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.activeTabIndex = this.tabGroup.selectedIndex;
  }
```

On [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9uvqzk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) is also a working example. The summary here is just for sake of clarity if someone else don't want to look first in github and stumbles herein.